# Can Brago's ability keep Traft's angel token around?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I attack with [Brago, King Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrago%2c%20King%20Eternal%5d) and [Geist of Saint Traft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGeist%20of%20Saint%20Traft%5d), can I have Brago's ability flicker the Traft angel token so that it won't be removed at end of combat?

Related:
Can I flicker Traft and Brago as well so that they are untapped?

Related:
If I have a [Pentarch Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPentarch%20Ward%5d) on Traft, can I flicker both the ward (to get another card) and Traft (to make him untapped) without losing the Pentarch Ward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a token would leave the battlefield to any other zone it will cease to exist.

> 110.5g A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

You can flicker your traft and brago and yes since they are entering the battlefield they would be untapped and also have summoning sickness.

If you flicker a creature that's enchanted the enchantments would be removed and sent to the graveyard. Now if you flicker both the ward and the creature then I'm not sure but you might have to enchant another creature aside from the one re-entering since they enter at the same time and the enchantment wouldn't "see" the creature flickered along with it.

Comment: Do permanents flickered by Brago really return at the same time? I was thinking perhaps their return could be ordered like when multiple abilities trigger at the same time.

Comment: If they have ETB abilities you could stack those anyway you like. As for the cards being flickered they all leave simultaneously and return simultaneously.

Comment: The brago ability goes on the stack you chose the permanents you want to flicker and then it resolves by flickering the chosen nonland permanents all at once

Comment: Taken from Brago, King Eternal's oracle text:

> If you exile an Aura with Brago’s last ability, the Aura’s owner chooses what it will enchant as it comes back onto the battlefield. An Aura put onto the battlefield this way doesn’t target anything (so it could be attached to a permanent with shroud, for example), but the Aura’s enchant ability restricts what it can be attached to. The Aura can’t enter the battlefield enchanting a permanent that enters the battlefield at the same time. If the Aura can’t legally be attached to anything, it remains exiled.

Comment: @Greg The objects enter the battlefield at the same time. However, you are correct in that each object gets a different timestamp when they enter, and if multiple objects enter at the same time, the active player determines their relative timestamps. See rule 613.6c + j. Timestamps are important to correctly apply continuous effects under certain conditions.